# Hide Drop-down arrow in combo-box Windows 8

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro

How to disable Drop-down arrow in combo-box in Metro-style app(Windows 8)

Answer (score 1):

If you permanently want to disable it, just edit the ControlTemplate. You can remove this, the popup... or do a variety of other basic template edits to cause it to not to function anymore.

In particular, the named entity DropDownGlyph:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DropDownGlyph" Grid.Column="1" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush}" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
    Margin="0,0,6,4" Text="&#xE011;" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

If it's a temporary thing, given your scenario of wanting to toggle, then the easiest would be to use two controls, a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox`. Toggle the Visibility (using The `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` and `BooleanNegationConverter` which is included in many of the VS2012 templates) based on another property (such as `ShowAsComboBox`). Bind both the TextBlock and the ComboBox to the same property. As long as both controls share a common parent and location, it should look fine.

Comment: My problem is i want the combo-box to look like a Text-block in one case in another case i want the same combo-box to look like combo-box with drop down arrow.At run time i wanted to switch in both modes.

Comment: Updated answer with a simple technique.